# ADS1115 ADC + ESP32 4S battery monitor

Tags: batteries, adc, esp32, battery-monitor

I have a project to monitor a 4S battery pack with an ESP32 using an [ADS1115](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1115.pdf) ADC. I have previously tested the circuit witch has been corrected by someone on Stack Exchange. The circuit:

[image]

I have 2 questions about my circuit:

1. Can I use the same ADS1115 to read 14.8, 11.1, 7.4, and 3.7 V DC corresponding to A0, A1, A2, A3 of the ADS?
2. I am not in continuous read with the ESP32 digital out read. Can I read the 4S DC voltage if there is a load that drains 3 A from the power bank without damage to the ADS1115?

Comment: Wiring of Q2, Q5 (no collector resistor), R7 seems weird ?

Comment: `I have previously tested the circuit witch has been corrected by someone on Stack Exchange.` the circuit doesn't seem to be "corrected": **1)** AIN0 will always measure the H2 voltage. **2)** When Q5 is driven with `digiout-esp32` it'll short the bank and a significant current will flow. This may result in damaging the batteries. **3)** Q2 is always forward-biased so R5 will always see the bank voltage. But the R7-Q2-R5 network is already shorted by H1 so there's no point in driving Q2 here.

Comment: Thanks Rohat  I understand what you meen but why on a power supply the circuit work that the point i dont understand?

Comment: Can you please explain what the purpose of `digitout-esp32` is?

Comment: the purpose is do drive ads115 ic to not be in continuous read mode